# create custom decorator in django based on url paramenters

Tags: python, django, decorator, django-urls

I have two login urls:

1. /profile/login/
2. /mob/profile/login/

And I have a view,

```
@login_required
def favorited_spreads(request ,page_template='spreads/favorited_spreads_ajax.html',
        template='spreads/favorited_spreads.html',mode=None):
    profile = request.user.profiles
    spreads = profile.favorite_by.all()
    context = {
            'spreads': spreads,
            'profile': profile,
        }
    if request.is_ajax():
        template=page_template
    return render(request, template,context)
```

And my two urls are:

```
 url(r'^favorites/$',
    'favorited_spreads', name='favorited_spreads'),
url(r'^mob/favorites/$',
        'favorited_spreads',{
               'template':'mobapps/spreads/favorited_spreads.html',"mode":"mob"}, name='favorited_spreads_mob'),
```

Now my question is, I want a decorator instead of `@login_required` say `@custom_login_required`, in which if the user is not authenticated and going to url `/favorites/ here mode=None`, it should be redirected to url `/profile/login/`.

And if he is going to url `/mob/favorites/` (here mode='mob')with out authentication he should be redirected to login url `/mob/profile/login/`.

Any help is highly appreciated. If the question not clear please comment.

Answer (score 0):

My self created a custom decorator for the same,

```
def custom_login_required(function,redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    def wrapped_func(request,mode=None, *args,**kwargs):
        login_url=settings.MOBILE_LOGIN_URL if mode else settings.LOGIN_URL
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return function(request, mode=mode,*args, **kwargs)
        path = request.build_absolute_uri()
        # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
        # use the path as the "next" url.
        login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(login_url or
                                                    settings.LOGIN_URL)[:2]
        current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse.urlparse(path)[:2]
        if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
            (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
            path = request.get_full_path()
        from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
        return redirect_to_login(path, login_url, redirect_field_name)
    return wrapped_func
```

here `settings.MOBILE_LOGIN_URL` is `/mob/profile/login/` and `settings.LOGIN_URL` is `/profile/login/`

Here I used the function `django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test` with relevant modification. But still I am unaware how can we reuse the django built-in decorator `@login_required`  for the same.